# Insert with PrimaryKey=ForeignKey

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I have two tables:

```
File
|- Id (Primary Key)
|- Name
|- ...

SpecificFile
|- FileId (Primary Key & Foreign Key to File.Id)
|- SpecificProperty1
|- ...
```

I have the following Linq2Sql code (LINQPad):

```
 var sfiles = from f in File
              where f.Name LIKE 'Specific%'
              select new SpecificFile { FileId = f.Id, SpecificProperty1 = "Foo" };
SpecificFiles.InsertAllOnSubmit(sfiles);
```

However, the insert fails with:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_SpecificFile_File". The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabase", table "dbo.File", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

The reason is clear if I debug and look at the Linq2Sql-generated INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO [SpecificFile]([SpecificProperty1])
VALUES (@p0)
```

How to inform Linq2Sql that it has to use a specific ID for insertion?

Note: setting the `File` object reference to `f` in the `new`-expression doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself...unfortunately, SpecificFile.FileId was set to  `IDENTITY(1,1)`. The exception message didn't help much ...